# Line clamp is not working properly in mozilla firefox? but the same working on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using line clamp to truncates text at a specific number of lines. for example clamp for 3 lines.my code is working properly on chrome, but on firefox the text is not truncating propelry as this div which having class name as description having two elements one is paragraph and another is unordered list items. so on firefox it is truncating the child element text instead of parent element text (considering it as different two elemets)for reference see this image [Result on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGQZD.png),On chrome tuncate properly text in 3 lines as example **It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more a normal distribution...**

```css
.description{
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more a normal distribution about df</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Why resilience is the The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more a normal distribution</li>
    <li>How helping others helped her develop the confidence to overcome setbacks</li>
    <li>Changing hrer lorem set lump to not allow sum to feel like a post more</li>
  </ul><br>
</div>
```

gone through this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/ but still the text is not truncate properly on firefox for reference see this jsfiddle attached here on chrome and firefox both and the code given
[clamp multiple lines](https://jsfiddle.net/anitacontents/nzdtLb4h/12/)

Comment: `-webkit-` doesn't apply to Firefox. Even the article you pointed to says, "So, what’s the catch?
As of right now, it’s browser support. Line clamps are part of the CSS Overflow Module Level 3 which is currently in Editor’s Draft and totally unsupported at the moment.

We can get some line clamping action with a -webkit- prefix (which, weirdly enough, works across all major browsers). In fact, that’s how the demo above was done."

Comment: -webkit-line-clamp is known to have all number of problems, which is why you can only access it through the otherwise obsolete `display: -webkit-box`. As j08691
 says, a better designed line-clamp property is being prepared, but it's not there yet. In the meantime, problems with the experimental prefixed property just need to be lived with.